# How to check (if else) with soundfile? obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I made an array with sounds, for example: sound 1, sound 2, sound 2, sound 1, sound 3. The user can touch four buttons. Button 1 for sound 1, button 2 for sound 2, etc. I want the user to touch the right button in the sequence of the array.

I created the buttons and the array with sounds, my question, how do I check whether the user touched the right button or not?

Cheers

Comment: "An array with sounds".  Please show the types you are storing as they are probably filenames of sound files, rather than buffers of audio (which would be a bad design for mobile deployment).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to assign tags to the buttons (0 for button 1, 1 for button 2 etc.)

Declare one `IBAction` method and connect all buttons to it.

In the method get the tag of the button (the sender) which is the proper index of the sound array.